# Android: setMultiChoiceModeListener(Contextual Action Mode) isn't invoked immediately

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I have a listview and I want to show a menu(Contextual Action Mode) when I do a long click on the list. It doesn't work when I click the first time, but other times it works. I noted that onItemLongClick is always called, but the Contextual Action Mode starts only the second time.
Here is my code:

```
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    stringList = new LinkedList<>();
    stringList.add("A");
    stringList.add("B");
    stringList.add("C");
    stringList.add("D");
    stringList.add("E");
    listView = getListView();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,stringList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    final AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener choiceModeListener = new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.contentmenu2,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    };

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"LONG CLICK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed the problem modyfing this part of the code:

```
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In this way the context menu starts because I call it twice, but I don't understand why I have to call it two times...